# Your hardware does not support this application. Failed to load "libmain.so"

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, unity-container

I tried to add Unity as a library to Android Studio and I got this error when I click on button that take me to unity app, there is no compile or build error. unity app works fine alone, also android app. this problem occurs when i tried to embedded unity in android
this is the error

[Failed to load "libmain.so"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egQkL.png)

I tried these solutions and nothing works with me:
1-run the app with many devices and emulators
2-change player sittings on unity
3-add this to App level's gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
}
```

4-add this to Module's build.gradle

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Comment: This error sometimes happens when you try to load Unity on the wrong architecture. Is the device you're running on `x86`, `x86_64`, `armeabi-v7a`, or `arm64-v8a`?

Comment: I used X86 emulator

Answer (score 4):

the solution is:

1- make sure you checked this [target architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJP7N.png) form Unity player settings before exporting your Unity app.

2- when you open exported unity app on android studio go to App's level `build.gradle` and copy ndk block it will be similar to this.

```
 ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
```

3- paste it on `defaultConfig` block on the targeted android app.

4- on `strings.xml` file on the targeted android app paste this.

```
<string name="game_view_content_description">Game view</string>
```

Comment: this does not work: you still get the error of libmain.so not being found